# failed disk size increase with LVM

Tags: boot, lvm

I tried to increase the hard disk of my virtual box machine. On this VM a standard ubuntu installation with LVM was active.

1. I increased the hard disk with vboxmanage
2. I increased the partition with gparted
3. I adapted the LVM with

   ```
   lvextend -l 100%FREE /dev/mapper/intern-root
   ```

Unfortunately, I forgot to execute `resize2fs`, I restarted the server

Now, the server does not start. It is missing the root device, loading the initramfs shell.

Is there any possibility to reanimate the server or do I have to reinstall the complete system?

Comment: Can you boot from another medium (USB, CDROM, Network),  mount/fix the LVM volume, run `resize2fs`, thne unmount and reboot the server?

Comment: No, unfortunatelly I am not able to mount the device. I am able to boot from an ubuntu live cd and I can see the lvm partition in gparted with "File System: unknown" and an exclamation mark.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't execute `vgextend` before `lvextend`, the volume group `intern` should still have the same size and be on the same physical volume.
In my view, the problem is unrelated to extending the LV.

It's just that the physical volume on which the VG is located has been resized so perhaps LVM simply doesn't find the VG.

You may be able to recover from this by booting a rescue system and trying to find the volume group headers on the physical volume. `vgck` and `cgcfgrestore` may help here. Perhaps [this](http://blog.adamsbros.org/2009/05/30/recover-lvm-volume-groups-and-logical-volumes-without-backups/) or [that](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Cluster_Logical_Volume_Manager/mdatarecover.html) might help. Good luck!

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not able to search for volume group as I am not able to mound the partition starting the rescue disk.